# htc one s android update - how?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-one-s

I have a new HTC One S, which is now running 4.0.4. Although I understood that HTC released the update to 4.1, when I check for updates (Settings -> About -> Software updates -> Check Now) it returns "There are no updates available for your phone".

Do the guys in HTC push the update in chunks of devices? Can I advance myself in the queue? Can I ask for the update?

Comment: Is it an international HTC One S or is a branded one (e.g. AT&T) ? Because when it is a branded one, it can take some more time. Patience is a virtue :-)

Comment: @ndsmyter: I got it in Germany without any contract - So I guess it is not branded then, right?

Comment: Probably not. A branded phone can be recognized by the brand logos everywhere, so you would've known. And you would have bought it together with a subscription to that brand.

Answer (score 1):

Software updates are released by the mobile network of the device as well as the device manufacturer.

It normally goes like this:

- Google release a new Android version.
- Manufacturers take this new Android version and modify it to work on their devices.
- *Manufacturers test the version, and push it out to unlocked devices first via desktop software update and then via OTA update if available*.
- Mobile networks/Carriers then take the Android version modified by the Manufacturer and modify it themselves to add carrier specific apps/features.
- Carriers pass it onto the manufacturer to release to the public [OR] carriers release it to the public via their custom OTA app.

As such, it can take some time to get the update, however I would advise you check using the desktop program if there is one.

Comment: I know that a friend already got the update (OTA as far as I know). Anyway, I'll try find a desktop sync program.

Comment: @Dror Is your device branded? Make sure it is the official HTC one, as that will give out updates.

Comment: How can I verify this? I got it from MediaMarkt, and it is not bounded to any contract. What is meant by "official HTX one"?

Comment: Make sure you get the sync software made by HTC, and is the device unlocked? Or is it locked to a network/carrier?

Comment: Do you mean the desktop tool? I am now downloading the software (available only for WIN...) My phone is not locked and I can use it through any carrier/network.